# Ensuring Consistent Response Structure with Gemini API

Tags: prompt, google-gemini, google-generativeai, gemini

I'm building a project that leverages the Gemini API, but I'm facing an inconsistency issue. Every time I send the same prompt, the response structure changes, making backend processing difficult.

The desired behavior is to receive responses with a consistent structure, regardless of content variations. This structure should ideally include:

An introductory paragraph 3-4 paragraphs containing the main content A concluding paragraph However, subsequent requests with the same prompt sometimes lack the title or begin with different elements, disrupting my processing pipeline.

Could you advise on how to achieve consistent response structure from Gemini API, even when the content varies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give the prompt you're using to generate the reply, but in general, Gemini is better at following *examples* rather than following *instructions*.

So your prompt should probably look something like:

```
You will be asked a question. Your reply should include a title, a 
descriptive paragraph, and a concluding paragraph as illustrated below.

Example question: What is the meaning of life?
Example reply:
Title: About life
Description: Life. Don't talk to me about life.
Conclusion: All the circuits down my left arm

Question: [put the question here]
Reply:
```

Answer (score 2):

> Every time I send the same prompt, the response structure changes, making backend processing difficult.

You will need to tune your prompt and keep tuning it until you get a more consistent response. There is no easy way to get 100% the same response from an LLM each time.

I have major issues when i try to have it parse the response to json even the json structure will change. Your code will need to handle these edge cases.

Comment: I think, For the ease i have write different prompts for each pattern one Prompt for generating intro part, another for paragraph and another for conclusion.this way i can easily handle the response.